# Nested CSS grid acting strangely

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If you look at the nested grid in Firefox and look at the grid display you will see the four separate nested grids each with 1 row and 12 columns. However, if you look at the CSS file you can only assign the element "main-services-text", "main-banner-text", etc., by treating it as a single 4 row grid.

So my question is, is this the way it should work or is it a bug. Also should I use it?

```css
.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

/* Step 1a assign the main elements "" to the MAIN Grid*/

.main-banner {
  grid-column: 1 /13;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.main-services {
  grid-column: 1 /13;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.main-why-us {
  grid-column: 1 /13;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background-color: orange;
}

.main-who-are-we {
  grid-column: 1 /13;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  background-color: chocolate;
}


/* Step 2: Set up individual nested GRIDS*/

main section {
  display: grid;
  color: olive;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}


/* Step 2 assign elements to the nested grids  */

.main-banner-text {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.main-services-text {
  grid-column: 6 / 9;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.main-why-us-text {
  grid-column: 10 / 13;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.main-who-are-we-text {
  grid-column: 9 / 10;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-grid">
  <section class="main-banner">Banner</section>
  <p class="main-banner-text">Main banner text</p>
  <section class="main-services">Services</section>
  <p class="main-services-text">Main services text</p>
  <section class="main-why-us">Why Us</section>
  <p class="main-why-us-text">Main Why us text</p>
  <section class="main-who-are-we">Who are we</section>
  <p class="main-who-are-we-text">Main who are we text</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. The grids are doing exactly what you're asking them to do in your code. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi Micheal. Sorry if I wasn't clear I was referring to the face that if you inspect the elements in Firefox and look at the grids you will see four individual grid that start are row 1 and end at row 2.

Comment: However if you look at my HTML the section with the class "main-who-are-we" I would expect to specify grid-column: 9 / 10; grid-row:  1 / 2; to add text where it appears on the HTML page.  This however does not work and I have to enter grid-column: 9 / 10; grid-row:  4 / 5;.

This to me seams wrong as no rows 4 /5 show in the Firefox grid.  So I was wondering if its a problem with my code or Firefoxes grid. My hunch would be it was a problem with my code or how the browsers are interpreting my code rather than Firefoxes grid, as grid appears how I would expect it to.

Comment: Hi Micheal scrub that I have been a Numpty, forgive me I'm still learning and making silly mistakes. I wasn't nesting the <p> tags in the <section> tags. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but wasn't sure: that the paragraph elements weren't actually nested in the sections. Okay, good luck.